# Cura 2.4 missing "split object into parts"

Tags: slicing, ultimaker-cura

I have an stl with multiple parts that I want to split up. Cura 15 had an option to "split object into parts" but I can't find that in cura 2.4. Did it get removed?

Comment: Right clicking a model, does NOT show "split model" at any point. Did cura do away with this? I can't believe that they would...

Comment: @Brian - please see [this comment](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/3732/cura-2-4-missing-split-object-into-parts#comment6246_4324)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think this feature was implemented at all with Cura v2.x.

As the developers say on the v2.1 release, "Cura has been completely reengineered".

Finding proper changelog documentation appears to be pretty hard because they have not posted any actual changelogs except the "user friendly viewable" changelogs which only list additions of new features but don't display what everything they changed between each version of their application.

Here is the most complete changelog I could find. I do not see any mention of this feature. https://ultimaker.com/en/products/cura-software/release-notes

Going through the Cura 2 manual or the Cura 2.1 FAQ, also does not mention this feature.
https://ultimaker.com/en/resources/20406-installation-cura-2-1

Furthermore, searching around for version 2 "split objects" lead to forum posts of people suggesting to use some other software to achieve this specific task. If you decide to go this route, I recommend Meshmixer from Autodesk to manipulate your models and then export to STL and import them to Cura either as a whole new position set up or separate model files where you can change them there as you need to (meshmixer allows for object repositioning around a defined build plate so you can just import the whole assembly into cura and then print).

It might also be worth to put in a feature request on the UM forums.

Answer (score -1):

I think they removed it because it was inefficient (pretty slow). Still, I just started 3D printing and was a bit disappointed a seemingly easy task needed an other software (Meshmixer) to be achieved.

Comment: Is this just your guess, or have you heard from someone at Ultimaker that they removed it because it was too slow?

Comment: We haven't removed it. We just haven't reimplemented it. Cura 2 was a reimplementation of the whole frontend.

Answer (score -1):

Nope, not in my version 2.4+

Seems like something so useful and silly to have to get yet another program to make it work.  Like that is somehow faster?   I have no problem with slow.

Can't believe it would be slower than hopping into another program, opening file, dividing file, saving stl file, then reloading into Cura again...  Cura slicing it would need to be awfully slow for that to be faster.

Comment: Although this question has been answered (and accepted) and commented by one of the developers, the value of bringing this up after more than a year does not seem useful as your answer does not add new information. It adds an opinion. An addition would be if it would have been reinstated from version X; but the version I use (Cura 3.2) does not have the option either.

Comment: right... my opinion that it is a feature that should be available but is still not implemented more than a year after the initial comment.

Answer (score -2):

You can split STL files in Cura 2.4
Just open your STL file in Cura and right click it.
Select "Split object into parts"

Comment: Are you sure? The other answers suggest the feature is not present in Cura 2.x, including a comment from someone who apparently works at Ultimaker.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot?